# Finding the density of a liquid using archimedes principle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics, density

I'm practicing some physics problems and came across one that's essentially this. **An an object of mass $m_o$ has apparent mass $m_o'$ when submerged in a particular liquid. Derive a formula to determine the density of the liquid.**

I solved it and got the equation  $\rho_f = \frac{(m_o)(\rho_o)}{(m_o - m_o')}$. The correct answer, however, is a little different and looks like $\rho_f = \frac{(m_o - m_o')(\rho_o)}{m_o}$ and I can't figure out why for the life of me. How do you obtain the density of a fluid using archimedes principle?

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.